# Are Adobe Creative Cloud questions on-topic for Super User?

Tags: discussion, too-localized, on-topic

I was among the first to ask about Adobe's relatively new subscription-based service to supersede the former Creative Suite, Creative Cloud. Now, it appears that my questions on my new tag [adobe-creative-cloud](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/adobe-creative-cloud) are not receiving much attention, which I'm guessing is due to the fact that not many other users have it. I may be among the few users to have the subscription. Therefore, although they are perfectly on-topic for Super User (despite the name, Creative Cloud is not entirely a cloud-based offering as it offers client-based applications, because, as I said, it is meant to supersede the Adobe Creative Suite), they seem very localized to me. Would such questions be on-topic still?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is some overlap depending on whether the question involves local programs or not.

- If the question is about a local application (e.g. Photoshop CC), then it would be **on-topic**.
- If it were about the interaction between a local application and the online service (e.g. uploading from Photoshop CC), it would be **on-topic**.
- If the question were about the use of a solely remote service (e.g. online management of files) it would probably be **off-topic** and better suited to [Web Applications](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/).

---

As for usage, I (and probably some others) actually do use Adobe CC - but sometimes we just don't know, or maybe didn't see the question. And of course many people subscribed to the other tags wouldn't be notified. [Your own question](https://superuser.com/questions/685119/what-limitations-are-there-when-i-try-to-run-an-adobe-creative-cloud-application) is a rather obscure use case, and I wouldn't be able to answer that. I'm not sure how many others would have the setup and time to test it, let alone find themselves in the same situation.

It also generally helps to tag your questions with the specific program, where possible. Again, I'll use [adobe-photoshop](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/adobe-photoshop) as an example. You're more likely to find people who know about a specific program than the whole range. Unfortunately, this doesn't really apply to your current questions (one is about the suite as a whole, the other is about a brand new prerelease product).

Comment: You're right; not many people can use RemoteApp as it is only available to users of Enterprise/Ultimate versions of Windows Vista/7/8/8.1 (and Windows XP Professional with an update), as well as with Windows Server 2008 and higher. In my case, the fact that I am a student entitles me to a free copy of Windows Server 2012 R2 Datacenter.

Comment: Well, the second question is not entirely about the prerelease product. It's about the Creative Cloud application. Are questions about the Creative Cloud desktop application on-topic here?

Answer (score 2):

As an irregular SuperUser I thought I'd chime in to say that while it might be on topic here that you're more likely to find a audience who can answer the question in a more specialised stack.

I suggest having a meta discussion with [GraphicDesign](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/) since they field a lot of usage questions on the Adobe graphics products and [Audio-Video Production](https://video.stackexchange.com/) for Premiere and see what they say.

Comment: My questions are about the Adobe Creative Cloud desktop application, which I don't think is on-topic for either.